# javascript как корректно указать путь к файлу находящемуся на несколько уровней выше

Tags: javascript, html, json

Есть файл data.json и он находится на несколько уровней выше, чем файл HTML и js_scripts и вот **как правильно считывать в Javascript локальные файлы находящихся вне папок проекта** ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

    <select id="mySelect">
        <option>football</option>
        <option>Basketball</option>
        <option>Hockey</option>
        <option>Swimming</option>
    </select>

    <p>
    Click the button to select the
    option element with index "2".
</p>

    <button onclick="myFunction()">
    click me

    <button onclick="Func()">
    click me_2

</button>

    <script>

        // 1. method: read local file and show them in console.log
        fetch('./data.json')  // ------ > как указать к файлу на несколько уровней выше (или абсолютный путь ?)
        .then(res => res.json())
        .then(data => {
            console.log(data)
            console.log('this type:' + typeof(data))    // show data_type of data
            console.log(data['Сергей']) // read by key of json
        })

    </script>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Ну вы как минимум написали `./data.json`, что не есть правильно т.к. `.` указывает на то, что файл находится в текущей директории.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте таким образом:

```
fetch('../../data.json')
```

Comment: Спасибо )  .... Вам